# Sinatra, Pony gem: NoMethodError

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

I am trying to send an e-mail using Pony and get the
**NoMethodError at /

undefined method `address' for #Mail::Message:.** error. This is my code so far:

```
post '/' do
Pony.options = { :from           => '___@yandex.ru',
                 :via            => :smtp,
                 :address        => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
                 :port           => '465',
                 :user_name      => '___',
                 :password       => '___',
                 :authentication => :plain, 
                 :domain         => "http://127.0.0.1:9393/"
                }
Pony.mail(subject: 'Hello', to: "___@yandex.ru", body: 'hi')
redirect '/'
end
```

when running **bundle list** it does show **pony (1.10)**. What could go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:address`, `:port`, etc. go inside a `:via_options` hash.

Per [the documentation](https://github.com/benprew/pony):

```
  :via_options => {
    :address        => 'smtp.yourserver.com',
    :port           => '25',
    :user_name      => 'user',
    :password       => 'password',
    :authentication => :plain, # :plain, :login, :cram_md5, no auth by default
    :domain         => "localhost.localdomain" # the HELO domain provided by the client to the server
  }
```

Therefore, you'll want:

```
post '/' do

  Pony.options = {   
                   :from           => '___@yandex.ru',
                   :via            => :smtp,
                   :via_options    => {
                     :address        => 'smtp.yandex.ru',
                     :port           => '465',
                     :user_name      => '___',
                     :password       => '___',
                     :authentication => :plain, 
                     :domain         => "http://127.0.0.1:9393/"
                    }
                 } 

  Pony.mail(subject: 'Hello', to: "___@yandex.ru", body: 'hi')

  redirect '/'

end
```

Comment: Right, corrected it, now it pends forever and gives me **Net::ReadTimeout**.

Comment: Anything useful in the mailer log?

Comment: I'll posted one more question and would greatly appreciate your help there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188703/sinatra-timeout-error-on-post.