# Pony yandex.ru and mail.ru specifics

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pony

I am creating a form in Sinatra that will be sending data to an e-mail on submit using Pony gem. This is my code so far:

```
post '/pemco' do 

Pony.mail(
  :from => params[:name] + "<" + params[:email] + ">",
  :to => '___@yandex.ru',
  :subject => params[:name] + " has contacted you",
  :body => params[:message],

  :via => :smtp,
  :via_options => { 
    :address              => 'smtp.yandex.ru', 
    :port                 => '465', 
    :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
    :user_name            => '___', 
    :password             => '___', 
    :authentication       => :plain
  })
redirect '/' 
end
```

I press *submit*, response pends for some time and then I get **Net::ReadTimeout
file: protocol.rb location: rescue in rbuf_fill line: 158** error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's got to be a proxy problem somewhere in communicating with `smtp.yandex.ru` ...  Do you have access to the this SMTP machine to check the logs there?

Comment: @CDub, it finally worked with another mail agent, I think there is some specific problem with yandex. could you tell me what you mean by *SMTP machine* so that I know how to approach this problem? Thanks for helping.

Comment: I'm not familiar with what Yandex is... Is it a service?  If so, I'd like to have a peek at their documentation to see if maybe Pony is set up correctly / needs to be tweaked.  I'll do some googling, but if you have direct documentation, that could be helpful.

Comment: @CDub, those are russian search engines, and I just got them both to work by setting **to:** and **from:** fields to the same address and changing port in one of them (yandex) to 25, even though in docs (https://help.yandex.ru/mail/mail-clients.xml) it says it requires port 465!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works for **yandex.ru** (and you need to go here https://mail.yandex.ru/neo2/#setup/client and allow everything):

```
post '/sent' do
  Pony.mail(
    :to => "_yourEmail_@yandex.ru",
    :from => "_sameYourEmail_@yandex.ru",

    :via => :smtp,
    :via_options => { 
      :address              => 'smtp.yandex.ru', 
      :port                 => '25', 
      :enable_starttls_auto => true, 
      :user_name            => '_yourUsername_', 
      :password             => '_yourPassword_', 
      :authentication       => :plain
    })
end
```

And same code works for **mail.ru** (and generally you don't need to do anything else).

Comment: Worked for mail.yandex.com as well